# $\frac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}$ to $\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So somehow my professor converts $\frac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}$ to  $\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)}{2}$ and I don't understand how. Can somebody explain the steps to do this please?

Comment: Factor the $(n+1)$ so $n(n+1)+2(n+1) = (n+1)(n+2)$

Comment: Common factor...

Comment: In the first, factory by $(n+1)$ so (n+1)(n+2)  and (n+2)=(n+1+1)  so (n+1)((n+1)+1)

Comment: Factor this the same way you factor $(ab + ac)$ as $a(b + c)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominators are the same (namely, $2$).  For the numerators,

$$\color{blue}n(n+1)+\color{blue}2(n+1)=(\color{blue}n+\color{blue}2)(n+1)=(n+1+1)(n+1)=(n+1)((n+1)+1).$$